# Is there a SQL function to count unique ids where address is the same but names are similar?

Tags: sql

| name | address | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| carl smith | 14 unicorn ln. | 1 |
| Carl Smith | 14 unicorn ln. | 2 |
| anthony bell | 1734 university ave. | 3 |
| carl Smith | 14 unicorn ln | 4 |
| janet wilson | 1734 university ln | 5 |
| Janet Wilson | 1734 university ln | 6 |

How can I get a count of unique customer id's for each address where names are similar? The dataset is too long to use ilike 'carl smith',and then ilike 'janet wilson'. the line would need to be broad enough to include any possible similar names that pop up throughout .

Desired Result:

| address | id count |
| --- | --- |
| 14 unicorn ln. | 3 |
| 1734 university ln | 2 |

it would also be helpful if I could get a list of the similar names associated with the same address.

Desired Result Pt. 2:

| address | similar name |
| --- | --- |
| 14 unicorn ln. | carl smith, Carl Smith, carl Smith |
| 1734 university ln | janet wilson, Janet Wilson |

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags (and the tag for the SQL client which is irrelevant). Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference is the case of the names, then use `upper()`/`lower()`.  For the results you specify:

```
select address, 
       count(*) as num_names,
       array_agg(name) as distinct_names
from t
group by address, lower(name);
```

This becomes much trickier if you have to deal with other variations, such as middle initials.  If that is your problem, then ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and a clear explanation on how to identify if two names are "similar".

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 PostgreSQL functions to get fuzzy matches between 2 strings.  Read about then here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/fuzzystrmatch.html

Comment: Link only answers are not quality answers, nor are tips - both suited to comments unless you are intending to provide an actual solution.